# create a folder in remote server and copy a file there in vb.net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, networking, vb.net-2010

I tried searching on net for hours but couldn't get any useful answer. It would be of great help if I could be provided with a code accomplishing this.

I have IP address of a remote server which is password protected (it needs user name and password to login)
I need to write a code in VB.NET that creates a folder in this remote server and copies a file from local server (in which the code is executing) to the remote server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically possible, its a way of hacking.

Thats why we have other technology to do it i.e. FTP, SFTP, Webdav.

I would suggest you to do same, use either of above technologies and do your stuff.